# Dynamic_reconfigure's .cfg file synchronization with parameter's changes

Tags: rosparam, synchronization, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello folks!

I'm wondering is there a simple way to update your .cfg file (used by dynamic_reconfigure tool) with the changes you make during program run? So that each time you restart roscore, the parameter's server uploads the latest changes you put via rqt_reconfigure, without manually updating your .cfg file.

I found similar question regarding Rosparam package without certain solutions. So maybe somebody came up with it for Dynamic_reconfigure pack?

I would appreciate if you can provide your solution with roscpp.

Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224262/dynamic_reconfigure%27s-.cfg-file-synchronization-with-parameter%27s-changes/) by [postal](https://answers.ros.org/users/25034/postal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-01-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-01-18**:
I would really like to have that: a dynamic dynamic reconfigure, but the cfg has be compiled so it doesn't seem possible.  I'm working on a system for dynamically creating a bunch of topics with types and mins, maxes, types and having an rqt gui get created for https://github.com/lucasw/v4l2ucp

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-01-18**:
Maybe it could save the parameters to a `~/.ros` temp file, or be configured to load and save initial value params from a defined location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've loaded ros params that were in turn saved to disk by an earlier instance of the same node that upon init override the cfg provided defaults.  There were some complications with exactly when the parameters ought to be set to prevent the cfg defaults from overriding.  TBD put some more details in here later.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [postal](https://answers.ros.org/users/25034/postal/) on 2016-02-23**:
Thank you for your reply! Looking forward for your updates

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-05-09**:
I think I misunderstood dynamic reconfigure before, the params in the node namespace ought to override cfg defaults, so rosparam dump to yaml, followed by a load from the same yaml ought to work.